# How to find out in which locale it was encoded to?

Tags: python

I have one byte class object and I need to convert it into string. I used .decode("format") method (format = UTF-8, latin-1, UTF-16. etc) First I want to know that in which locale it is encoded so that I can decode it to that proper locale.

Comment: You are probably looking for its encoding, not its locale.  It is near impossible to tell from a single byte which encoding it's in.  If the input is being read from user input, the current system locale is probably a good heuristic, but for e.g. a web form the HTML in the form controls the encoding, and for a byte in a file on disk it's basically impossible to tell without additional external indicators.

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure if its what you're looking for but i guess you can use [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet)

```
import chardet
result = chardet.detect('string')
encoding = result['encoding']
```

Comment: Yes it gives me the encoding type but when I drag the text and use decode(encoding) then it gives me some other thing. it should return me UTF-8 or just english text simply

Comment: when you decode a string, you will get unicode.
if you want to get 'utf-8' or any other encoding:
first, detect the encoding, decode it, and then encode it to any encoding you want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use locale.getdefaultlocale() to determine the default locale settings, visit [Internationalization services](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) for more detail.

Comment: I think it will give me the system default locale settings. I need to find out for that particular byte class encoding locale.

Comment: could you put your code in here? sorry I am a little confused about one byte class has its encoding locale.

Comment: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gtg/gtg/trunk/view/head:/GTG/gtk/editor/taskview.py#L185 line 185 gives error. As GtkSelectionData dont have .data attribute need to replace that with .get_data() method which returns the byte class object and insert_at_cursor() accept string.

Comment: Doesn't the `datatype` parameter tell you anything?

Comment: Nope datatype don't tell anything. :(